# What is the domain of $\arccos(2x/(1+x))$?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I need to find the domain of the given function y=$\arccos (2x/(1+x))$. How should I approach this?

Comment: First and above all: what is the "natural" (usual) domain of of the function arccos? Second, what **exactly** is the argument of your function? It seems to be $\;\frac{2x}{1+x}\;$ ? Use parentheses for clearity.

Comment: Ok thnks.I know natural domain of arccos is (-1,1) but what about the domain of this function?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

For $\arccos (♥)$ we have $-1\leq ♥ \leq 1$.

Now in the inequality substitute $♥=\frac{2x}{1+x}$ and try to solve it for $x$

**Hint 2**

Remember, that the denominator in fractional have to be nonzero.

Comment: Ok when we take both cases separately then there will some values satisfying less than equal to case and some satisfying greater than equal case. Now which value we have to choose? Intersection or union of values?

Comment: It have to satisfy both of the inequalities, so...